# ion auth group based login

Tags: php, codeigniter, ion-auth

```
$groupadmin ='1';
if ($this->ion_auth->in_group($groupadmin))
{
    $this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'You must be part of the group 1 to view this page');
    redirect('dashboard');
}else
{
    $this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'You must be part of the group 2 to view this page');
    redirect('test');
}
```

if group id = 1 then user redirect dashboard and group id = 2 then user redirect test controller but both login user redirect test controller

Comment: Show your `in_group()` function code.

Comment: i am using Ben Edmunds Ion Auth library for codeigniter

Answer (score 2):

You can change your code groupadmin variable in interger only.

```
$groupadmin = 1;
if ($this->ion_auth->in_group($groupadmin))
{
   $this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'You must be part of the group 1 to view this page');
   redirect('dashboard');
} else {
   $this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'You must be part of the group 2 to view this page');
   redirect('test');
}
```

you can visit this url for your reference http://benedmunds.com/ion_auth/#in_group

Comment: please approve this answer for it can be helpfull for others.

Comment: Upvoted for the reference link. A shame this answer isn't accepted